# three column layout with image at bottom

Tags: css

I have a three column layout. I need to stick an image at the bottom of each box. How can I do that?

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="item1">hello <img src="example1.png" /></div>
   <div class="item1">test <img src="example2.png" /></div>
   <div class="item1">hi <img src="example3.png" /></div>
</div>
```

How do I align the image at the bottom of each div, given that they have variable heights?

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
.item1 {
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

 <div class="item1">
    <p>hello<p>
    <img src="example1.png" />
</div>
```

if this works use it for other divs as well and if you want these divs to be side by side then do

```
.box {
display:flex;
}
```

Hope this helps

take care and happy coding